# How to create a msbuild target to run after "Run" target (dotnet run)?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to create a msbuild csproj where I can invoke `dotnet run myproject` and get bin/obj folders deleted after execution. **However, the `CustomAfterRun` target (below) does not get executed after the Run target.**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomAfterRun" AfterTargets="Run">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="[msbuild] Cleaning bin and obj..."/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(TargetDir)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

If I create a target `CustomAfterBuild` (with `AfterTargets="Build"`), it works fine (it gets executed after the build when I run `dotnet build myproj`).

**Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?**

And the crazy part: if inside `CustomAfterBuild` I invoke `<CallTarget Targets="Run" />` then after the build my program is invoked, and in this case `CustomAfterRun` runs fine !! The downside of this method is that the program output is only visible if I enable detailed verbosity level, and also after `CustomAfterRun` runs (deleting bin/obj folders) it will also try to run the program AGAIN (meaning that the Run target is invoked TWICE?!) giving me an error: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified.`.

**EDIT**: As an alternative I also tried overriding Run target, but that didn't work at all:

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <Target Name="Run" >
    <Message Importance="high" Text="[msbuild] overriden..."/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a wrong assumption about `dotnet run`.

- There's [`dotnet msbuild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild) which is basically a facade to invoke [msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019). [`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) is just a shortcut to `dotnet msbuild -restore`, so it will restore nuget packages and build (default target). [`dotnet clean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-clean) also invokes msbuild (clean target).
- In a similar sense **I was expecting [`dotnet run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) to use the `Run` target from msbuild, however it does NOT**. It invokes `dotnet msbuild` (if required), but it will run the output **WITHOUT** using msbuild.
  If I run `msbuild -target:Run` the post-run events work fine!

So one possible solution would be to use plain msbuild.
E.g.: `dotnet msbuild /t:Restore;Build;Run;Clean MyProj.csproj`),

However, another behavior which was annoying me is that when the program is launched through msbuild I don't get colors (if any) in console output. This is probably because msbuild uses console-redirection to run my program. `dotnet run` fortunately doesn't have this behavior, so my final solution will be:

`dotnet run & dotnet clean`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Clean is not so perfect, clear leftovers -->
  <Target Name="CleanBinObj" AfterTargets="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(BaseOutputPath)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
  </Target>

  <!-- If someone uses msbuild to launch, force a clean.. -->
  <Target Name="CustomAfterRun" AfterTargets="Run">
    <CallTarget Targets="Clean" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Or for my specific case where I'll keep multiple individual cs programs in the same folder (each one with their own csproj) and I want to override bin/obj folders with an individual (temporary) folder for my file:

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TempDir>$(MSBuildProjectName).cs.tmp\</TempDir>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(TempDir)</BaseOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(TempDir)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(MSBuildProjectName).cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Clean is not so perfect, clear leftovers -->
  <Target Name="CleanBinObj" AfterTargets="Clean">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Cleaning $(TempDir) (bin/obj)..."/>
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(TempDir)" />
  </Target>

  <!-- If someone uses msbuild to launch, force a clean.. -->
  <Target Name="CustomAfterRun" AfterTargets="Run">
    <CallTarget Targets="Clean" />
  </Target>
  
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />

</Project>
```